# iOS: What is the proper way to implement live audio streaming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, live-streaming

I'm developing an iOS application for a news website, the website has [a live audio news channel](http://198.178.123.23:8662/stream/1/;listen.mp3), i have tried using `AVAudioPlayer` and did the following:

.h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

.m file (viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://198.178.123.23:8662/stream/1/;listen.mp3"];

    NSError *error;
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfURL:url
                    error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

But the application is giving me the following error:

> 2015-05-25 15:03:12.353 AudioPlayer[2043:421434] Error in audioPlayer: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

I don't know what's wrong with this code.

Can anyone tell me where's the error in the code ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Read up on "apple HTTP live streaming" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html and https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way to play the audio link in the default MPMoviePlayer with audio url. Rest of the things will be managed by default player.

EDIT :

```
    NSURL *audioPath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Audio URL"];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:audioPath];
    // Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:mpViewController
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:mpViewController.moviePlayer];

    // Register this class as an observer instead
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:mpViewController.moviePlayer];

    // Set the modal transition style of your choice
    mpViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    // Present the movie player view controller
    [self presentViewController:mpViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Start playback
    [mpViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [mpViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because `AVAudioPlayer` doesn't support HTTP (meaning that you can't play media from the internet), so what you can do is use `AVPlayer` it's pretty much similar, here's an example :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://198.178.123.23:8662/stream/1/;listen.mp3";
    urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    self.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlStream];

    NSError *error;

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [_audioPlayer prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
    }
}
```

Hope my answer helped you :)